# What kind of polyhedron is this?

Tags: geometry, polyhedra

What kind of polyhedron is this? I understand 20 faces is the largest regular polyhedron, but this one seems to have 36 faces.

[image: Green Climate Fund logo]

Source: It is the logo of the [Green Climate Fund](https://www.greenclimate.fund/home)

Comment: You count 36 visible faces, but it amounts to approximately twice (72) if you include the hidden faces.

Answer (score 2):

(Incorrect) I think it is a [Pentakis dodecahedron](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentakis_dodecahedron) with $60$ faces, $90$ edges and $32$ vertices.
[image]
Here is the [rotating model](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Pentakisdodecahedron.gif).

**Edit:** It is actually a [Pentakis icosidodecahedron](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentakis_icosidodecahedron) with $80$ triangles
($20$ equilateral; $60$ isosceles), $120$ edges and $42$ vertices. (See the comments below)
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for a quick answer! Faces looked like perfect triangles, but I guess they are actually isosceles triangle, therefore it is not considered as a regular polyhedron?

Comment: A pentakis dodecahedron would have each pentagonal pyramid adjacent to five pentagonal pyramids, but that is not the case for the logo in question. I believe it's a pentakis [icosidodecahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icosidodecahedron), i.e. an icosidodecahedron with a pyramid on top of each pentagon.

Comment: @Rahul : I think you are right. Should I delete my answer or just edit it in this case?

Comment: Thank you Rahul and Tianlalu! In the corresponding wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentakis_icosidodecahedron , it says "It can also be topologically constructed from the icosahedron, dividing each triangular face into 4 triangles by adding mid-edge vertices. From this construction, all 80 triangles will be equilateral, but faces will be coplanar." Are you able to tell from the logo picture, if it is coplanar or not?